# How to make gdb command source use python 2 instead of python 3?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to debug c++ program. I source a script from gdb which is written in python 2.7 and it supposed to recursively print object values. Python 3 was already installed in my linux machine. So I installed python2.7 and now my machine has both python 2 and python 3. Now when I run the source command in gdb environment, it still uses python 3 and the script does not run. How do I set it to run on python 2.

I have tried setting alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7 in .bashrc. 
I do not want to uninstall python 3 as other services depends on it.

Expect gdb to use python 2 while doing source python script.

Answer (score 2):

> Python 3 was already installed in my linux machine. So I installed python2.7

Installing Python 2.7 will have to effect on GDB: what matters is which version of Python was your copy of GDB *compiled and linked* against.

To get a GDB built against Python 2.7, you will most likely have to build GDB yourself (use `--with-python=...` when configuring your GDB).